# Assertion Failure when using vcglib examples

Tags: c++, vcg

I want to use vcglib for reconstructing a surface based on a point cloud. But whenever I run my program (also with the provided examples, e.g. /vcglib/apps/sample/trimesh_allocate)  I get the following output:

> trimesh_allocate: ../../../vcg/simplex/vertex/component.h:50: int
>   vcg::vertex::EmptyCore::cFlags() const [with TT = MyUsedTypes]:
>   Assertion `0' failed.

Any ideas how to solve this? I am using QT-Creator 2.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I do net get any compiler or linker errors.

Thanks a lot in advance, Mirco

Answer (score 1):

In order to get rid of such an error you typically need to change the definition of the vertex, edge, face, mesh definition. I could get this example to work using:

```
class MyFace;
class MyVertex;

struct MyUsedTypes : public vcg::UsedTypes< vcg::Use<MyVertex>::AsVertexType,
vcg::Use<MyFace>::AsFaceType>{};

class MyVertex  : public vcg::Vertex< MyUsedTypes, vcg::vertex::Coord3f,  vcg::vertex::Normal3f, vcg::vertex::VFAdj, vcg::vertex::BitFlags, vcg::vertex::Mark>{};
class MyFace    : public vcg::Face  < MyUsedTypes, vcg::face::VertexRef,   vcg::face::Normal3f, vcg::face::FFAdj, vcg::face::Mark, vcg::face::VFAdj,  vcg::face::BitFlags > {};
class MyMesh    : public vcg::tri::TriMesh< std::vector<MyVertex>, std::vector<MyFace> > {};
```

I believe the `vcg::xx::BitFlags` are the ones that you need to add for both vertex and face. This can be seen from the error you have that is about cFlags().

Furthermore in the `trimesh_allocate.cpp` example, you need to comment out the following section:

```
// WRONG WAY of iterating: FN() != m.face.size() if there are deleted elements
/*for(int i=0;i<m.FN();++i)
{
 if(!fi->IsD())
   {
    MyMesh::CoordType b = vcg::Barycenter(*fi);
   }
}*/
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But It doesn't work for me... 
but other simple examples works for me.
Do you know how to Insert Vertices in the mesh?
I tired as explained in the example. But when i try to Insert `MyMesh::VertexPointer ivp[400000];` like 400k vertices. the program crashes with no error. Please help me Thank you.

Comment: If you make a new question and place the link here, I will answer it.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. I've posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628620/program-crashes-while-creating-vertexpointer-of-more-then-400k-vertex-in-vcg)